# PHP unlink() breaks file_exists, header, and echo functions?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$tmpfile = $tempDirectory . $file ;

if (file_exists($tmpfile)) {

   header('Location: <some location>');

}
```

It works flawlessly, the file exists, I get redirected to my new page.

So, now I know that the file exists and works. So, I go into FTP, ensure the file is there.

Then I run this code:

```
$tmpfile = $tempDirectory . $file ;

if (file_exists($tmpfile)) {

   unlink($tmpfile);
   header('Location: <some location>');

}
```

Redirect stops working. PHP outputs nothing. The file gets deleted from the FTP directory. But the redirect completely fails.

If I put an `echo` inside the if statement when there is an unlink present (before or after any other line of code in the if statement, it outputs nothing.

There isn't an unlink error, and the file is clearly deleted when I check FTP, so what is going on here?

It gets deleted when the code is run, so it's obviously not a permission issue. It wouldn't be able to delete the file if it didn't have permissions to do so.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The code `if (file_exists($tmpfile) == TRUE) {` may be replaced by `if (file_exists($tmpfile))`. Testing explicitly against `true` is not necessary.

Comment: the file no longer exist so there won't be a redirect, it never gets inside the condition

Comment: To Jocelyn: I understand that. I come from a C++ background, this code originally had it in the format you presented. I was simply putting that in for clarity.

Comment: To Ibu: The file isn't deleted. I don't run both of them right after the other. I ran two separate case tests. Even if I had done them right after the other, the first if statement does not contain an unlink, how could the file be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution may be simple:

```
[blank space] - this breaks redirect
<?php

// code
```

PHP may be also crashing on unlink. Make sure your [error_reporint setting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is set to E_ALL.

Comment: It would appear it is not as simple as a space. 

I'll be looking into your error report setting soon. Thank you.

Comment: And... up goes XAMPP, let's get a fresh ball of PHP Putty to play with and make sure this works.

Comment: WAMP is much more stable than XAMMP, i always wonder why people keep using XAMPP :)

Comment: It's a quick and dirty install. But fair point. I'll remember WAMP in the future, thanks!

I've tried the same code out on XAMPP, the unlink works, header redirect works. Something is up with our remote install of PHP. (This is going to be a fun day talking with IT)

Comment: Setting to E_ALL helped us get this issue pinned down with our hosting provider. Thank's Peter!